# S'opposer à une « invocation illégitime » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, formulation

Concernant la dernière bêtise d'un dirigeant, l'ACLU a affirmé entre autres :

> « Honte à tout membre du Congrès qui ne s'opposera pas clairement et
>   vigoureusement à cette **invocation** illégitime » ([traduction](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201902/15/01-5214871-trump-sapprete-a-decreter-lurgence-nationale.php) dans
>   La Presse, je souligne)
>
> [ [...] Shame on any member of Congress who doesn’t clearly and vigorously
>   speak out on this illegitimate invocation of emergency authorities. [...] ]
>   ([ACLU](https://www.aclu.org/news/aclu-comment-potential-national-emergency-declaration))

Le choix du mot [*invocation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/invocation) est-il adéquat et usuel dans ce contexte (...l'urgence nationale aux États-Unis pour construire un mur à la frontière avec le Mexique) : pourquoi ; autrement quel aurait été un meilleur terme ou une meilleure formulation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Invocation* me semble adéquat et correct ici.

On parle bien ici d'invoquer un article de loi.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/invoquer)

> **B.** − *Au fig.* **Qqn invoque qqc.** (moins souvent **qqn**). Mettre en avant (quelque chose, quelqu'un qui sert d'appui ou d'excuse). Synon. **alléguer, arguer de. Invoquer des arguments, une excuse, un précédent, un prétexte, une loi, un texte**.

Le terme *invocation* n'est plus limité aux contextes religieux depuis longtemps, et l'utilisation de ce sens figuré semble s'être accentuée depuis la fin des années 70.

[image]

Parler d'invocation illégitime consiste donc ici a considérer que l'esprit de la loi est dévoyé, que la loi est détournée de son objet.

Comment: Bon point à l'effet qu'il s'agit d'une [loi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Emergencies_Act) et non d'un pouvoir constitutionnel, ainsi que la démonstration d'un emploi moderne plus marqué du sens figuré qui le détache du sens religieux...